# busted WS2811 LED strip by overpowering, totally useless now?

Tags: led-strip, troubleshooting, ws2811

Powered a 5V WS2811 LED strip with 12V by accident. It turned on for a split second, it fried a microcontroller, I noticed the smell and turned everything off as fast as I could.

When i tried powering the LED strip again with 5V (also exchanging for a new microcontroller of course) only the 2nd LED in row turned on. I cut off the first 3 LEDs and soldered the wires on again, but now nothing turns on.

Does that mean the whole 5m LED strip is busted or is it possible some LED+ics further down the line could be salvaged?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Even if some are working, nothing guarantees that they aren't damaged inside with severely limited lifetime. Since they are cheap, just replace them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the ICs in the strip are powered in parallel. It is entirely possible that *every* chip in the strip is now broken.